# Error when free struct

Tags: ios, memory, struct

I'm beginner developer iOS.
I'm running this code on device then error.

```
/**
 * Structure to keep one pixel in RGBA format
 */

struct pixel {
    unsigned char r, g, b, a;
};

/**
 * Process the image and return the number of pure red pixels in it.
 */

- (NSUInteger) processImage: (UIImage*) image
{
    NSUInteger numberOfRedPixels = 0;

    // Allocate a buffer big enough to hold all the pixels

    struct pixel* pixels = (struct pixel*) calloc(1, image.size.width * image.size.height * sizeof(struct pixel));
    if (pixels != nil)
    {
        // Create a new bitmap

        CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(
            (void*) pixels,
            image.size.width,
            image.size.height,
            8,
            image.size.width * 4,
            CGImageGetColorSpace(image.CGImage),
            kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast
        );

        if (context != NULL)
        {
            // Draw the image in the bitmap

            CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, image.size.width, image.size.height), image.CGImage);

            // Now that we have the image drawn in our own buffer, we can loop over the pixels to
            // process it. This simple case simply counts all pixels that have a pure red component.

            // There are probably more efficient and interesting ways to do this. But the important
            // part is that the pixels buffer can be read directly.

            NSUInteger numberOfPixels = image.size.width * image.size.height;

            while (numberOfPixels > 0) {
                if (pixels->r == 255) {
                    numberOfRedPixels++;
                }
                pixels++;
                numberOfPixels--;
            }

            CGContextRelease(context);
        }

        free(pixels);
    }

    return numberOfRedPixels;
}
```

Error is : PTP(4821,0x3ece6d98) malloc: *** error for object 0x45a9e00: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug.

Please help me fix this error.
Thanks's so much.

Comment: I think error from  : pixels++;

Answer (score 2):

This is an old thread but I thought I'd post an answer here.

The error is in the pixels++ line. As @Michael pointed out, the address was getting changed inside the loop. My solution was to replace the entire while block with the following:

```
for (int i=0; i<numberOfPixels; i++) {
    if (pixels[i].r == 255) {
        numberOfRedPixels++;
    }
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you maintain a pointer to the original value of `pixels` after calling `calloc`. This is the address you need to pass to `free`. You're changing this address inside your loop.

Comment: I'm change my code : 
 while (numberOfPixels > 0) {
     if (pixels->r == 0 && pixels->g == 0 && pixels->b == 0) {
                    numberOfRedPixels++;
                }
                pixels++;
                numberOfPixels--;
            }
           
to :    for (int i = 0 ; i < numberOfPixels; i ++) {                
        if (pixels[i].r == 0 && pixels[i].g == 0 && pixels[i].b == 0) {
                              numberOfRedPixels++;
    }               
   }

Comment: Please post an update in your question. This is difficult to read here.